# sending model to view along id after save() in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my controller I am defining a model and persisting it to the DB with save() :

```
$model = new Model();

$model->attrib = "something";

$model->save();
```

Ok so now I want to send this newly created data to my view like this:

```
return view('new_model', ['new_model' => $model]);
```

The problem is the data passes to the view but not the id assigned to the model in the DB.
How can I possibly send this data without performing a new query to the DB after the `save();`
Shouldn't the `$model->save();` save to the DB and return what it persisted in the DB along id and all the stuff?

**I stand corrected, the id was appearing at the end of the data.**

Comment: didn't `$model->id` work?

Comment: I modified the question check it out

Comment: BTW: A good practice would be to redirect to a new page after every data modification by the user. One reason is to prevent that the user submits the same data reloading the page. You can see that on some forums when people submit duplicate posts.

Answer (score 2):

$model->id should be the last id inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent allows you to fill models by passing an associative array with values, and the keys representing the column names.

```
$model = Model::create([
  'attrib' => 'something',
]);
```

You will get the id by $model->id.

Hope it works. :)